# Would the Entity Framework's navigational properties work if I drop foreign key constraints from the database?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

As you know that developers mostly mock the relationship between tables instead of using physical relationships between table (yeah, the line drawn from one table to another if you put a foreign key constraint on the column).

But I believe that Entity Framework doesn't work properly if physical relationships aren't there for navigational properties.

So, is there any way around?

My classes:

```
public class Phones
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public List<Users> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Sims
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

This creates a 1-M relationship from User -> Sims.

But what if I drop the foreign key constraint and leave it as it is, how will the navigational properties work then?

Comment: You would need to run a migration

Comment: At this case better to also remove `List<Users> Users` from `Phones` and add `int UserId` to `Sims` and handle users of `Phones` manually and externally

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: Put that in answers box so I can mark. Also, I just figured that out before your answer but you made it sure that I am right. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this case better to remove references from both classes and handle relations manually outside of these classes:

```
public class Sims
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    //public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Externally ? means?

Comment: Means outside of these classes

Comment: like in database or apis